# Syntax in Assigning to Map of structs

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct, c++11, initializer-list

```
struct Structure {
//  Structure(const char* n, int v, bool a) : name(n), value(v), awesome(a) {}
  const char* name;
  int value;
  bool awesome;
};
std::map<const char*, Structure> map;
map["alpha"] = {"Alpha", 0, true};
map["beta"]  = {"Beta",  1, false};
map["gamma"] = {"Gamma", 2, true};
```

G++ (4.6) accepts this syntax of assigning in C++03, but complains that 'extended initializer syntax is only available in C++0x' (paraphrasing). I know that I can make a constructor that accepts the values in order, but I wanted to know if this syntax is acceptable (w/o C++0x), or is G++ just appeasing me because I'm so anxious for C++0x.

Compiling with clang++ doesn't even allow it (w/ C++0x, I'm assuming initializer lists are lacking), saying 'expected expression', which basically means "What the hell is that?", and even when I used the constructor (commented out above), it throws errors.

**Summary:** So basically, what is the correct syntax to use and can I use the initializer list format (in C++03 or C++0x)?

Comment: Even, if some compiler allows this syntax. It's better to avoid this for C++03, because in future if you add some constructor inside `Structure` then, the whole code will break.

Comment: I confirm that initalizer lists are not implemented in Clang (it was just asked yesterday on cfe-dev).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above code is only legal in C++0x by using the new uniform initialization syntax.  C++03 will reject this.  In the interim, defining a constructor for your `struct` is the way to go.

Comment: `C++0x will reject this`? I think, you mean *C++03 will reject this.*?

Comment: Whoops!  That was dumb. :-). Fixed.

Comment: Actually, since `map["alpha"]` will default construct the entry, I suppose he could provide a setter: `set(map["alpha"], "Alpha", 0, true);`

Comment: @Matthieu, or may be overload `operator()`?

Comment: @Nim: As much as I appreciate nifty syntax, I'd prefer a named function here :)